# Which FTP program can I use with SourceTree?

Tags: internet, ftp, php

I am using SourceTree from Atlassian to manage my source code for a personal project (a small project). I would like to know if Atlassian offers an FTP client/program which can interface with my SQL database.

The reason for asking is because I would like to know if:

- Does such FTP client from Atlassian exist?
- If one does, is it a good idea to use this order to keep everything under the same umbrella: SourceTree + FTP client.
- Does it integrate with SourceTree at all?
- Am I going in the wrong direction here, meaning is this such an irrelevant question that I can leverage any FTP client and there will be no difference at all?

I am mostly seeking some enlightenment here, my experience with FTP clients is very limited (FileZilla), so I appreciate all suggestions as long as **they are well justified**.

Comment: Any program(s) Atlassian might offer to purchase would be on their website.

Comment: @Ramhound that's fine but I don't even know what product is an FTP client by looking at their site, keep in mind I have **very** limited experience with FTP

Comment: It would be advertised as an FTP client.  If you can find no Atlassian  product, advertised or described as an FTP client on their website, then it is safe to say Atlassian does not make an FTP client.

Comment: @Ramhound in the case that their FTP client is out of the question (any reason) do you have any recommendations of other FTP clients you are comfortable with?

Comment: @DavidPostill that's very useful thanks! Would it be too much to ask to move this question over to that site? Maybe I could get more help that way

Comment: So, you want to access an SQL database with a program that shows it as if it were a filesystem? Or do you need a SQL-to-FTP gateway?

Comment: Yes exactly, access a SQL database using a file transfer program. I was wondering if such a thing existed for Atlassian, if it did then was it a good idea to use if I wished to integrate with Sourcetree (etc), or will any FTP do the job, meaning Atlassian FTP if it exists is as good as any other FTP